# Как создать ярлык на рабочем столе с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, frontend

Нужно чтобы у пользователя появлялось сообщение вроде этого: "Хотите ли вы добавить ссылку на этот сайт на рабочий стол", и если пользователь нажимает 'Да' на рабочем столе появлялся ярлык с ссылкой на сайт. Не обязательно JavaScript, но желательно без back-end'а

Comment: с помощью JS'a нельзя. На enSO есть ответ интересный - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509736/ddg#13510297

Comment: Работая в браусвере вы работаете в песочнице которая построенна так чтобы из неё ничего не "вылезло", исключение - IE с ихним "гениальным" ActiveX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имеется введу JavaScript выполняемый в вебе, то никак.
Если выполняемый Node.js то как обычный файл - см.документацию.

Answer (score -3):

у меня не вышло как вы хотите но на python можно сделать так:

```
a =input("Введите адрес: ")
b =input("Введите ведите имя файла: ")

my_file = open(b+".bat", "w+")
my_file.write("echo off \n start " + a)
my_file.close()

input()
```

и создаться файл который будет после активации кидать на сайт.